# Problems starting countdown timer from handler

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I get notification with socket.io to start a countdown timer in my android app. I use a Handler to send data from the socket.io callbacks to the UI thread. Handler messages work perfect. But starting the countdown timer from the handler doesn't work (onTick() function won't called). If I start it with the UI element, everything is ok. What is the best way to do it, when the countdown timer is operated not from the UI thread?

```
    mHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {

            mBattle = (Battle) inputMessage.obj;

            switch (inputMessage.what) {

            case NO_BATTLE:
                System.out.println("got message NO_BATTLE");
                break;
            //.................

            case START_BATTLE:
                startCountdownTimer(mBattle.getCountdown());
                System.out.println("got message START_BATTLE");
                break;
        }
    }
```

and the countdown timer function:

```
    private void startProgressBar(final int time){
    if (time != 0) {
        new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress " + i  + " " + 
                        + millisUntilFinished);
                i++;

            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                i=0;
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Comment: use mHandler instead of CountDownTimer to count diwn

Answer (score 0):

Did you print out the value of `time` when it's not working? If `time < SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000`, then `onFinish` will be called without calling the `onTick`.

Comment: thx..  ;)  i'm just stupid and have forgotten to multiply seconds with 1000. when i tried with button it was always already multiplied